# Check whether a color passed as argument to a package is defined

Tags: color, packages, arguments

I'm trying to write a small package that defines an accent color based on a choice of faculty for use in a template. If the faculty doesn't exist, I want to generate an error message. I currently have the following:

thecolors.sty:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\providesPackage{thecolors}{2021/07-05 v1.0 LaTeX2e document class}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\SetupKeyvalOptions{
  family = ugcol,
  prefix = ugcol@
}
% ug is the default if no faculty is given
\DeclareStringOption[ug]{faculty}[ug]
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\definecolor{ug}{RGB}{255, 210, 0}
\definecolor{lw}{RGB}{241,164,43}
\definecolor{re}{RGB}{220,78,40}

% Now I need something like (THIS DOESN'T WORK)
\ifdefined \csname\string\color@\ugcol@faculty\endcsname
  \xglobal\colorlet{ugaccent}{\ugcol@faculty}
\else
  \PackageError{theclors}{The faculty \ugcol@faculty \space doesn't exist}
\fi
```

I was told colors were stored by `xcolor` as `color@xxx`. So I'm trying to check whether `color@xxx` is defined, with `xxx` being the string found in `\ugcol@faculty`. But I'm obviously doing that in a very wrong way.

This package should then be used in a document as:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[faculty = lw]{thecolors}
\begin{document}

blabla some text.

\color{ugaccent} WHAT IS THIS COLOR?

\end{document}
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: the test should be `\ifcsname \string\color@\ugcol@faculty\endcsname yes \else no \fi`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that was exactly what I needed, thank you! If you can put it as an answer, I will accept as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comment by Ulrike Fischer: this problem was solved using `\ifcsname` like shown in the example here :

```
\ifcsname \string\color@\ugcol@faculty\endcsname
  \xglobal\colorlet{ugaccent}{\ugcol@faculty}
\else
  \PackageError{theclors}{The faculty \ugcol@faculty \space doesn't exist}
\fi
```